# How to get output value from python script executed in swi-prolog

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

How can I make a `swi-prolog` program that executes a Python file `score.py` and gets the output?

I've read about `process_create/3` and `exec/1` but I can't find much documentation

Comment: what do you mean by "gets the output"?

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of [the documentation of `process_create/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=process_create/3) that does roughly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `stdout/1` and `stderr/1` **options** of `process_create/3`.

For example, here is a simple predicate that simply *copies* the process output to *standard output*:

```
output_from_process(Exec, Args) :-
        process_create(Exec, Args, [stdout(pipe(Stream)),
                                    stderr(pipe(Stream))]),
        copy_stream_data(Stream, current_output),
        % the process may terminate with any exit code.
        catch(close(Stream), error(process_error(_,exit(_)), _), true).
```

You can adapt the `copy_stream_data/2` call to write the output to any other stream.